# Float stacking css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a joomla plugin that generates some html for a form. The problem I have is with the css.

The script generates several divs of varying height, all of which are stacked into a two column layout. The problem is that since they are all floated left, sometimes a second column tall div can block the next div from floating under the adjacent short first column div. Without further hand waving, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5FV9/1/)

What reasonably browser compatible css can I use to stack the floats correctly? Note that the second column divs have essentially no classes or ids to distinguish them from the first column divs.

Here are things I would preferably avoid:

1. Non compatible solutions like nth-child()
2. Changing the script to generate css hooks with the html

Javascript is sort of okay

EDIT: It seems the javascript comment is not prominent enough. As the jsfiddle stands, everything is working correctly. This is what I **want** the layout to look like. Unfortunately, I cannot use a `correctfloat` classname on the div, because I am not the one generating it. Remove the correctfloat classname to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, something similar to that. I would prefer a css solution though.

Comment: Well, seems that you're out of luck. Anyway, if you find something please post here as I would like to see CSS version of this, too.

Comment: posted my answer. i still can't get over how mind bogglingly amazing this library is. they should just bundle it with every browser.

Answer (score 1):

You use this style code in css file

```
#yourdiv{
 float:left;
 height:yoursizepx;
 width:yoursizepx;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The height of the div is not to be fixed, it expands to fit its contents.

Comment: use min-height instead of height,min-height for dynamic height

Comment: I apologise for being slow, but I cannot understand how this is relevant to my issue. Could you please demonstrate in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

using `clear: left` on the `short` class solves the issue in the example you've given:

```
.short{
    height:100px;
    clear:left;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/U5FV9/2/ and 
http://jsfiddle.net/U5FV9/3/

However I can't help but feel that it may not solve the issue always, based on the information you've given about dynamically a created form. For example, what if a `short` element needs to be on the right?

I think a better solution for you would be to have two column containers that are floated and contain your `short` and `tall` elements. That way you can always ensure they appear correctly.

Here's an example of how you could implement that:
http://jsfiddle.net/U5FV9/5/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that but it is not working, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U5FV9/4/). Also, like I said, the html is being generated by a 3rd party joomla component, and I would prefer not to have to fiddle with that.

Comment: @Asad to be fair, you've changed the code from the original question (taken `correctfloat` off the `tall` element). If the code is as you've given me now then please update your question as that will mislead answerers.

Comment: I had mentioned in the javascript comment, and also recently in the answer, that you should **remove** the correctfloat class to see what the problem is. The correctfloat is there to show the results I want, but cannot obtain.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case I think the [masonry solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12880498/733347) might be your best bet then, as you can't really achieve this just using CSS. That is why masonry exists after all, as long as it is usable when it doesn't work then all is good. May be the only route unfortunately as [`column-count`](http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/) is [a ways off](http://caniuse.com/#search=column).

Comment: Just found the perfect solution, the [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) library polyfills css support in all browsers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As per Mladen's request, I am posting the approach that worked best for me. I used an unobtrusive javascript library called [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) that enables cross browser support for the latest css in, get this, **all browsers**.

I then proceeded to use:

```
someclassname:nth-child(2n){
    float:right;
}
```

to align every second column div to the right, without the actual need for a second column container. It is still not a perfect solution, since theoretically it is still possible for divs to pile up on one side, but I haven't seen it happening so far.

Thanks for your help folks.

Comment: Thanks, but as you've said, still not perfect solution. I'd still stick with masonry plugin and have predictable results ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, have you tried modifying or adding an overflow property on the block?

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: I am not sure how this would work. Could you please demonstrate by putting this in the fiddle?

Comment: @Asad overflow:hidden hides the content that exceeds the limit of the contents container. http://jsfiddle.net/4KckC/1/

Comment: Correct, but this has nothing to do with my question. I do not need to hide the overflow on a fixed width div, it simply expands vertically to fit its content. My question pertains to how I can stack aforementioned divs correctly, as demonstrated in the jsfiddle, without using a class name for the second div.