# Stacking float css

Tags: html, css

**PROBLEM**: cannot stack floats with CSS only.

In the example http://jsfiddle.net/9YQXP/7/ I have 3 divs whose width is 35% of its container. I will not know in advance the height of each div but I'd like the third div to stack right beneath the first one.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a1">a1</div>
<div id="a2">a2</div>
<div id="a3">a3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#a1, #a3 {
    height:20px
}
#a2 {
    height:30px
}
```

**OTHER ANSWERS:** a similar question ([Float stacking css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880308/float-stacking-css)) has been answered with a link to http://masonry.desandro.com/. However, it has been answered with a javascript solution and I too would prefer CSS only (or a working example with masonry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with CSS alone. Per the [specs for floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> 5) The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the
>   source document.

Comment: What if I resort to fixed widths and control responsiveness with media queries? Do you think it's worth spending time or just look for a JS solution straight away?

Comment: Personally, I'd go the JS route.

Comment: Would it be difficult to provide a short example (or a reference to one)?